# jquery ajax item can not be clicked after reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, reload

I am using django

In the body block

```
<div id="tag_like">
    {% if liked %}
      <img id="unlike" title="unlike" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}pic/bad.png" />
    {% else %}
      <img id="like" title="like" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}pic/good.png" />
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

In the on_ready script block:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
});
$('#like').click(function() {
   $.post("{% url 'likevideo' %}", {uid:{{ login_id }}, videoid:"{{ videoid }}"}, function(data,status){
      $('#tag_like').load(' #tag_like')
   });
});
$('#unlike').click(function() {
   $.post("{% url 'unlikevideo' %}", {uid:{{ login_id }}, videoid:"{{ videoid }}"}, function(data,status){
      $('#tag_like').load(' #tag_like')
   });
});
```

It works fine at the 1st time you click the image.(turned to the other image)
But when click it again, no ajax action happens. I read

[Refresh a div in Django using JQuery and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217919/refresh-a-div-in-django-using-jquery-and-ajax)

[jqgrid not reloading after making a ajax call using trigger('reload')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754953/jqgrid-not-reloading-after-making-a-ajax-call-using-triggerreload)

[Adding jQueryui Buttons to dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028912/adding-jqueryui-buttons-to-dynamically-added-content)

But no specific solution reached yet...
Any solution with minimal changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for event binding:

```
$('#tag_like').on("click", "#like", function() {
   $.post("{% url 'likevideo' %}", {uid:{{ login_id }}, videoid:"{{ videoid }}"}, function(data,status){
      $('#tag_like').load(' #tag_like')
   });
});
$('#tag_like').on("click", "#unlike", function() {
   $.post("{% url 'unlikevideo' %}", {uid:{{ login_id }}, videoid:"{{ videoid }}"}, function(data,status){
      $('#tag_like').load(' #tag_like')
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.on()` because you are loading `DOM` to div with ID of `tag_like`.

```
$(document).on('click','#like',function(){
    //code here.
});
```

Comment: exactly! Thanks for this small but brilliant change!

Answer (score 0):

Do it like:

```
$('#tag_like').on("click", "#like", function() {
   $.post("{% url 'likevideo' %}", {uid:{{ login_id }}, videoid:"{{ videoid }}"}, function(data,status){
      $('#tag_like').load(' #tag_like')
   });
});
```

This method is fast because it will prevent jQuery from parsing whole document each time you click on the button.

Comment: True, except missing a "," after "#like"